# Make changes to a tuple via pattern matching

Tags: elixir

I want to change a specific part of a tuple. Is it possible to use pattern matching?

```elixir
{1, [{:reach, [:s, :d]}, [link: [:s, :d]]]}
```

I want to change reach to `:reach_1`.  I can fetch the reach field but cannot modify the whole tuple.

```elixir
{id, [{item, _}, _]} =  {1, [{:reach, [:s, :d]}, [link: [:s, :d]]]}

:"#{item}_#{id}"
```

How can I add it back to the tuple replacing `:reach` ?

Comment: You may want to consider using a map if you need a data structure that must be frequently/easily modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using pattern matching, because you would effectively have to write-out the full tuple again. [`put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3) is designed for putting data into nested structures. You can acheive what you want by using it  with [`Access.elem/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#elem/1) and [`Access.at!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#at!/1):

```elixir
{id, [{item, _}, _]} = foo = {1, [{:reach, [:s, :d]}, [link: [:s, :d]]]}
put_in(foo, [Access.elem(1), Access.at!(0), Access.elem(0)], :"#{item}_#{id}")
```

Or just writing out the tuple again:

```elixir
{id, [{item, rest1}, rest2]} = {1, [{:reach, [:s, :d]}, [link: [:s, :d]]]}
{id, [{:"#{item}_#{id}", rest1}, rest2]}
```

Result in both cases:

```elixir
{1, [{:reach_1, [:s, :d]}, [link: [:s, :d]]]}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It's a datalog structure and it's always going to be the same. Hence `pattern matching` will be a better option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the tuple has always the same structure you can extract the fixed part and compone the new tuple:

```
> {a, [{_, b}, c]} = {1, [{:reach, [:s, :d]}, [link: [:s, :d]]]}
> {a, [{:reach_1, b}, c]}
```

In Elixir you cannot change a data structure, you can create a modified copy of that.

Actually there is a [`put_elem`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_elem/3) function in `Kernel` module that creates a new tuple with an updated element, but in your case the code would result to be complex since you need to change an element inside a nested list/tuple.